# Proving "Let $x$ be a real number. If $a \leq x$ for every $x > b$, then $a\leq b$"

Tags: inequality, logic

> Prove "Let $x$ be a real number. If $a \leq x$ for every $x > b,$ then $a\leq b$" in three ways: directly, by contradiction, and by contrapositive.

So, I did the direct prove:
for every $x>b,$ there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x-b = \epsilon >0.$

$$\begin{align}a&\leq x\\
\implies a-b &\leq x-b\\
\implies a-b &\leq \epsilon\\
\implies a-b &\leq 0\\
\implies a &\leq b. \end{align}$$

Is this correct, or does it have an error?

Comment: [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: thanks for the advice, it was my first time posting a question :)

Comment: @Creamenoodle: From https://math.stackexchange.com/conduct: Prefer gender-neutral language when uncertain.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: thanks for the tips, I think i surely need to know how to write notations.

Comment: No, $a- b\leq \epsilon$ does not imply $a-b\leq 0.$

Answer (score 1):

> So, I did the direct prove:
>
> for every $x>b,$ there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x-b = \epsilon$
> $$\begin{align}&a\leq x\\\implies{}& a-b \leq \epsilon\color{blue}{>0}\\\color{red}{\implies}{}& a-b \leq 0\end{align}$$

Unfortunately, the red implication is illogical and incorrect.

> > Prove "Let $x$ be a real number. If $a \leq x$ for every $x > b,$ then $a\leq b$"

Rephrasing the given statement:

- For each $(a,b,x)$ in $\mathbb R^3,\,$ if (if $x>b,$ then $a\le x),$ then $a\le b$
- $\forall (a,b,x){\in}\mathbb R^3\quad\big((x>b\implies a\le x)\implies a\le b\big).$

Can you continue from here? (Hint: $\;P\Rightarrow Q\;\equiv\;\lnot P \lor Q.)$

Answer (score -1):

> "Let $x$ be a real number. If $a \leq x$ for every $x > b$, then $a\leq b$"

I think that the problem composer intends that you use 
*proof by contradiction*
to prove the assertion.

Given:
$a \leq x$ for every $x > b$

To Prove:
$a \leq b.$

**Proof**

Assume that the conclusion is false. 
This implies that $a > b.$ 
This implies that $(a - b) > 0.$ 
This implies that $~\dfrac{a-b}{2} > 0.$

Then set $~x = b + \dfrac{a-b}{2}.$

Then, each of the following is true:

- Since $~\dfrac{a-b}{2} > 0,~$ 
  You have that $~x - b > 0 \implies x > b.$
- You also have that $~\displaystyle a - x = 
  a - \left[ ~b + \frac{a-b}{2} ~\right]$ 
  $= \displaystyle \left[ ~a - b ~\right] - \frac{a-b}{2} = \frac{a-b}{2} > 0.$
- Therefore, since $~a - x > 0, ~a > x.$

---

Therefore, the assumption that $~a > b~$ has led to a contradiction.

That is, this assumption has led to the conclusion that a specific value
of $~x~$ exists, such that

- $x > b.$
- $a > x.$

Since this contradiction of the premises of the problem was caused by the
assumption that $~a > b,~$ the assumption that $~a > b~$ must be false.

Therefore, it is now proven that $~a \leq b.$